# Now when Chrome is 64-bits, how do I install the Java plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, java, 64-bit, 32-bit

As long as Chrome just was 32 bit, the Java plugin was not supported since Java for Mac OS X is 64 bit but now when Chrome (since version 39) is 64 bit, how do I install/enable the Java plugin?

Googling just returns old results such as

https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml (that refers to this blog post http://blog.chromium.org/2014/08/mac-chrome-when-im-sixty-four-bits.html)

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2429779?hl=en (talking about Java 7, I have Java 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [the latest version of Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/), install, and reboot, and it should be listed in `chrome://plugins`. Make sure that it's enabled (there should be a button saying `Disable`):
[image: Java Plugin]

Note: You probably want to check `Always allowed` because Java always pops up and asks you if you want  it to run.

Once you finish this, you can [test java](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Java but I didn't reboot (and really don't have time for that now) since I saw no suggestion that I should reboot while installing.

Comment: Did this work? If it did, please click the check mark on this answer so it turns green and people can see that you have found a solution.

Comment: I will as soon as I have restarted, which I guess will be next time there is an update that requires reboot.

Comment: Yesterday I rebooted and it worked.